# Weka - Update Instances during evaluation

Tags: validation, machine-learning, weka, evaluation, updatemodel

I am using Weka API to test an algorithm. During the evaluation, I want to update some of the Instances (feature vectors) after evaluate each Instance. Here is my method now

```
    for(int i = 0; i < testDataset.numInstances(); i++) {
        // get current validation instance
        Instance curInst = testDataset.instance(i);
        // get actual class index
        int actualClassIdx = (int)curInst.classValue();
        // get predicted class index
        int predClassIdx = (int)bestClassifier.classifyInstance(curInst);

        if(actualClassIdx == predClassIdx) {
            numCorrect++;
        }
        // update validation dataset
        updateFeatures(testDataset);
    }
    double accuracy = (double)numCorrect / testDataset.numInstances();
    System.out.println("Testing accuracy = " + accuracy * 100 + "%");
```

This works, however, I want to use things like Evaluation object to help me do this because I need more statistic data (e.g: Confusion Matrix). Is there a sufficient way to achieve that?